# Multiple metadata classes for entity

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Suppose I have 2 entities one is `UserMaster` another is `ProjectMaster`, now there are few common properties in both the entities and I need to apply same data annotations and attributes on both set of common properties which I do using metadata classes, now my question is there any way that I have a common metadata class for all this common properties across entities,so that I don't need apply  data annotation and attributes for common properties again and again  and if yes then how to achieve this.

Comment: You can create a base metadata class and the other metadata class derive from the base and add some other properties.

Comment: thanks it worked for me

Comment: You are welcome:) I posted an answer with an example :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a base metadata class and the other metadata class derive from the base and add some other properties.

**Example:**

In the below example I supposed you can't derive `Class2` from `Class1` so I have inheritance only between metadata classes, otherwise you can simply have inheritance between your model classes.

```
[MetadataType(typeof(Class1Metadata))]
public class Class1
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

[MetadataType(typeof(Class2Metadata))]
public class Class2
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

public class Class1Metadata
{
    [Display(Name="Id1")]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Name1")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
public class Class2Metadata:Class1Metadata
{
    [Display(Name = "Description2")]
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```